# Which Membership Plugins Allow Registered Users To Bookmark Posts?

Tags: plugins, membership

I'm having some trouble finding plugins (free & premium ok) that would allow a registered member to essentially bookmark any post of interest to them while searching, and then revisit that bookmark through their user profile whenever their logged back in.

The only plugin that I'm aware of that has a related feature is the premium Wishlist Member plugin.

Specifically, what are other membership plugins that can achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search returns [WP Favorite Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/).  It sounds like this provides the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to mess with this plugin right now but you've given me whole new way to try and find other plugins that would fit what I'm trying to do. Thanks again!